# nothing is played am using python 3.5.1

Tags: python-3.x

nothing is played am using python 3.5.1

```
def add(a,b):
    answ=(a+b)
    print (answ)
    add(4,7)
```

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking.

Comment: whats is wrong with my code please

Comment: def add(a,b):
    answ=(a+b)
    print (answ)
    add(4,7)

Answer (score 0):

You need to dedent the last line

```
def add(a, b):
    answ = (a + b)
    print(answ)

add(4,7)
```

Otherwise it is part of the function body and won't be run

Comment: class calc:
    def adt(self,a,b):
        self.enter=int(input("enter here"))
        self.put=int(input("enter second digit"))
        self.ans=a+b
        print(self.ans)
last=calc()
last.adt()

Comment: @hunk , copy/paste of code in the comment field doesn't make it readable. Python depends on indentation, and we can't interpret your code like this. Edit your question and use code block for your code, please. Also specify what the problem is.